# Button Click does not fire JQuery Function

Tags: jquery, html, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

My Controller Has the actionresult:-

```
    [HttpPost]
    [LogInFilter]
    public JsonResult MemberCreate(GarhwalBhawan.Models.MemberTbl Mem) // Record Insert  
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.MemberTbls.Add(Mem);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(Mem, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(Mem, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }    

    [HttpGet]
    [LogInFilter]
    public PartialViewResult MemberCreate()   //Insert PartialView  
    {
        return PartialView(new GarhwalBhawan.Models.MemberTbl());
    }
```

In My View I have created a form and on button click I'm calling a json function as:-

```html
 <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Member Name
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Member Post
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Post)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Post)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Member Phone
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input id="memberSave" type="button" value="Create"  />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

and script function for MemberSave as:-

```js
@section Scripts {

<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#memberSave").click(function()  {
        var Name = $("#Name").val();
        var Post = $("#Post").val();
        var Phone = $("#Phone").val();

        var Member = {
            "Name": Name, "Post": Post,
            "Phone": Phone
        });

        $.post("/Admin/MemberCreate", Member,
        function (data) { if (data == 0) { location = location.href; } }, 'json');
    });
</script>
}
```

The problem is that on click of Create button it's not firing any the click event of JQuery.

Please Help.

Comment: use a proper event handler instead

Comment: Are you loading your script section into your master page?

Comment: Yeah , Layout page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you tagged this as jquery, so why not use jquery to attach the handler?

```
<input type="button" id="member_save" value="Create"  />

<script>


$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#member_save').on('click', function(){ 
       //your code here
     });

});

</script>
```

Comment: <input id="memberSave" type="button" value="Create"  />     $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#memberSave').on('click',function MemberSave() {
            var Name = $("#Name").val();
            var Post = $("#Post").val();
            var Phone = $("#Phone").val();

            var Member = {
                "Name": Name, "Post": Post,
                "Phone": Phone
            };

            $.post("/Admin/MemberCreate", Member,
            function (data) { if (data == 0) { location = location.href; } }, 'json');
        });
    });    Still Nothing happened

Comment: <input id="memberSave" type="button" value="Create"  />     $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#memberSave').on('click',function MemberSave() {
            var Name = $("#Name").val();
            var Post = $("#Post").val();
            var Phone = $("#Phone").val();

            var Member = {
                "Name": Name, "Post": Post,
                "Phone": Phone
            };

            $.post("/Admin/MemberCreate", Member,
            function (data) { if (data == 0) { location = location.href; } }, 'json');
        });
    });    Still Nothing happened

Comment: There's a warning :- Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.send @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8686. I can't figure out what's this.

Comment: I modified my question above. According to changes you have suggested.

Comment: Yes, I've added it in _Layout page under shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can add id to the button and click event of that id in this way.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myButton").click(function() {
        alert("button clicked.");
        //do ajax post here
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myButton" type="button" value="Create" />
```

Comment: Nothing happened when I changed the code to:- <br/>  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#memberSave').on('click',function MemberSave() {
            var Name = $("#Name").val();
            var Post = $("#Post").val();
            var Phone = $("#Phone").val();

            var Member = {
                "Name": Name, "Post": Post,
                "Phone": Phone
            };

            $.post("/Admin/MemberCreate", Member,
            function (data) { if (data == 0) { location = location.href; } }, 'json');
        });
    });

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happened? Did you changed your button code?

Comment: See this `};)};` how you managed it...then you told us **Nothing happened**, of course happens, see your console error at least

Comment: Yeah I missed it here. But in the code it is managed properly. I'm not getting error for this . Only a warning as:-  Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.send @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8686.

Comment: Then you should add managed code here! and put alert on button click and check. does alert popup?

Comment: No, I'll check again for possible errors and will post after that.

Comment: *I'll check again for possible errors and will post after that* Didn't get you!

Comment: I've updated the proper code now. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Please close the parenthesis properly..

```
    @section Scripts {

    <script type="text/javascript">

       $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myButton").click(function()  {
            var Name = $("#Name").val();
            var Post = $("#Post").val();
            var Phone = $("#Phone").val();

            var Member = {
                "Name": Name, "Post": Post,
                "Phone": Phone
            };)};

            $.post("/Admin/MemberCreate", Member,
            function (data) { if (data == 0) { location = location.href; } }, 'json');
});
</script>
    }
```